# How to optimize Mysql query with for loop

Tags: mysql

This query is taking long time to execute. Anybody tell me how to optimize this query?

```
$sql = '';
        $now = time();
        $until = $now + 604800;

        for ($i=0; $i < 7 ; $i++) { 
            $dayno = date('N', $now + ($i * 86400));
            $sql  .= "SELECT p.id, p.iam, p.offertimes, p.fromcity, p.tocity, p.days, p.parcel, p.seats, p.price, 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN days LIKE '%{$dayno}%' THEN 
                            (select unix_timestamp(addtime(timestamp(date(now())+{$i}),time(from_unixtime(deadline)))))
                            ELSE deadline
                        END AS deadline,

                            c1.nameRu AS 'from', 
                            c2.nameRu AS 'to', 
                            c3.nameRu AS 'city' 
                        FROM posts AS p 
                        LEFT JOIN citynames AS c1 ON p.from_id  = c1.id
                        LEFT JOIN citynames AS c2 ON p.to_id    = c2.id
                        LEFT JOIN citynames AS c3 ON p.city_id  = c3.id
                        WHERE p.deadline > {$now} ";
                        if ($i == 0) {
                            $sql .= "AND {$now} < (SELECT unix_timestamp(addtime(timestamp(date(now())), time(from_unixtime(deadline))))) "; 
                        }
                        $sql .= "AND p.days LIKE '%{$dayno}%' UNION ALL ";
        }
        $sql  .= "SELECT p.id, p.iam, p.offertimes, p.fromcity, p.tocity, p.days, p.parcel, p.seats, p.price, p.deadline, 
                        c1.nameRu AS `from`, 
                        c2.nameRu AS `to`, 
                        c3.nameRu AS `city` 
                    FROM posts AS p 
                    LEFT JOIN citynames AS c1 ON p.from_id  = c1.id
                    LEFT JOIN citynames AS c2 ON p.to_id    = c2.id
                    LEFT JOIN citynames AS c3 ON p.city_id  = c3.id
                    WHERE p.deadline > {$now} AND p.days = '' ORDER BY `deadline` ASC";
```

UPDATED: I have to 2 types of posts 1st is once and departure (e.g 25 march 2015, 7:00 AM), 2nd is regular and departure (e.g. every Monday, Friday, Sunday at 8:AM until 12 April 2015). What i want is: when user search code must convert all regular posts to 1st post type according to name of week day (until next week) but i must keep hours and minutes as old. I save my departure in one field (deadline) for regular posts additional filed (days). Here is my mysql table (short):

```
offertime|from_id|to_id|via_id|deadline  |days
2        |     52|   43|    73|1432036859|1,2,7
1        |     72|   65|    66|1424860459|
2        |     55|   23|    88|1425149999|1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

- offertime = 2 (regular)
- offertime = 1 (once)

Comment: why do you join 3 times the same table???show exanple of raw data and expected result of query?

Comment: Oops -- 3 joins are needed because 3 different rows are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggested improvements, plus lots of questions:

`posts` needs "compound" `INDEX(days, deadline)`.  Please show us SHOW CREATE TABLE so we can see the datatypes and indexes.

Can you avoid the leading wildcard in `LIKE '%{$dayno}%'`?  Please show us sample values for these.

`unix_timestamp(addtime(timestamp(date(now())+{$i})` --> `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + INTERVAL {$i} DAY`

Please explain what this is supposed to do.  It is not doing that!
`(select unix_timestamp(addtime(timestamp(date(now())+{$i}), time(from_unixtime(deadline)))))`
I say that because `time(from_unixtime('2014-01-01'))` = `16:33:34.000000`, which is probably not what you expected.

`{$now}` --> `NOW()`

$until is not used?

Would it make sense to JOIN to citynames after the UNION?

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( your union without citynames )
    LEFT JOIN citynames <3 times>
```

You have a complex expression with `deadline` buried inside.  Try to turn it inside out into

```
AND deadline > (some complex constant expression)
```

That way, an index might be usable.  (And hence speed up the query.)

Please "echo" the resulting SQL and let us critique that; it is hard to work from PHP.

Please put in the suggestions, get the echo, then let's go at it again.

Comment: Rick James I have tried add citynames after UNION but i could not :( i am new to MySQL. I have updated my question

Comment: Please echo the SQL after you have made whatever changes you can make.  I would much prefer to work with SQL without the PHP stuff interspersed.

Comment: SELECT p.id, p.iam, p.offertimes, p.fromcity, p.tocity, p.days, p.parcel, p.seats, p.price, CASE WHEN days != '' THEN (select unix_timestamp(addtime(timestamp(date(now())+6),time(from_unixtime(deadline))))) ELSE deadline END AS deadline FROM posts AS p WHERE p.deadline > 1424590473 AND p.days LIKE '%6%' UNION ALL LEFT JOIN citynames AS c1 ON p.from_id = c1.id LEFT JOIN citynames AS c2 ON p.to_id = c2.id LEFT JOIN citynames AS c3 ON p.city_id = c3.id

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this line is causing your performance problems:

```
AND {$now} < (SELECT unix_timestamp(
                         addtime(
                             timestamp(date(now())), 
                             time(from_unixtime(deadline)))))
```

It looks to me like you have a deadline each day for each row. The daily deadline seems to be `TIME(deadline)`.

Can you try to simplify this line, especially to get rid of the nested `SELECT`?

Maybe this will do the trick.

AND TIME(deadline) <= TIME(NOW())

Also, you seem to be repeating this query once for each of the previous days. It's possible you could run the query just once and group by day. But I don't understand your application well enough to try to do write that query.

Answer (score 0):

His query, pretty-printed and fixed some:

```
SELECT  p.id, p.iam, p.offertimes, p.fromcity, p.tocity, p.days,
        p.parcel, p.seats, p.price,
        CASE WHEN days != '' THEN 
            ( SELECT  unix_timestamp(addtime(timestamp(date(now())+6),
                time(from_unixtime(deadline)))))
            ELSE deadline
            END AS deadline
    FROM  posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN  citynames AS c1 ON p.from_id = c1.id
    LEFT JOIN  citynames AS c2 ON p.to_id = c2.id
    LEFT JOIN  citynames AS c3 ON p.city_id = c3.id 
    WHERE  p.deadline > 1424590473
      AND  p.days LIKE '%6%'
```

Can `'%6%'` be turned into simply `6` or at least `'6'`?  If so, we might have some more index opportunities.  Such as INDEX(days, deadline).

We have already discussed how ADDTIME is wrong; please fix that.

Notice that I got rid of the UNION (not necessary in this shortened version) and moved the WHERE to the end.

Didn't your original query have a UNION?